# SelectManyMenu binds values to backingbean Array instead of List

Tags: primefaces

Let's say I have a map like this in backingbean:

```
private Map<Integer, List<String>> map;
```

and i used it in xhtml like this:

```
<p:selectManyMenu value="#{fooView.map[user.userId]}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 1" itemValue="bar" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 2" itemValue="baz" />
</p:selectManyMenu>
```

when i try to get selected values in my bean:

```
 List<String> fooList = map.get(userId);
```

above line throws a `java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.util.List`

Thanks in advance.